# Fully fresh Ubuntu Install via terminal

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I have access to the server via ssh. I have only a terminal for controlling the server. I want to clean up it, reinstall it only via terminal. How I can implement this? I want a clean server for future work. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @nmath oh, but how I can reinstall my Linux on the server? Or I should delete my server, then setup it one more time?

Comment: How i can clean up it?

Comment: Ok, got it. Can I give you some reputation or something? Or please, write this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to reinstall your system while the same system is currently booted.

If you have physical access to the device you can use bootable installation media to reinstall.

If you are paying for hosting somewhere, most hosting providers have a toolkit that you can use to reinstall the operating system.  Check with the hosting provider for instructions or details.